# Revealing and hiding specific div with iframe inside with button

Tags: html, css, iframe

I´m just trying to do website for family member. I´ve got base html with css done, but there is one issue. I need to implement to page changing iframe that is linked to two kinds of forms in php. Right now I´ve figured out code for change hrefs, but these iframes have different heights so I want to close both of them into divs and reveal first or second with buttons.

Here is the code so far:

```
    <section id="predplatne" class="clearfix">
  <div class="predplatne_in">
    <h2>Text</h2>
    <div class="vyber">
      <button class="button"><a href="http://www.php" target="frame">1</a></button>
      <button class="button"><a href="http://www.php2" target="frame">2</a></button>
    </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="in">
      <iframe allowfullscreen frameborder="0" height="1700" id="frame" name="frame" src="http://www.php" width="480"></iframe> <a href="http://www.php" target="frame"></a> <a href="http://www.php2" target="frame"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JS for that. From what I've understood, you want to show an `<iframe>` when the button is clicked?

First off, create your `<iframe>`s and set both of their CSS `display` values to `none`, like so:

```
<div class="iframes">
  <iframe allowfullscreen style="display: none" frameborder="0" height="300" width="480" name="frame1" src="http://example.com"></iframe>
  <iframe allowfullscreen style="display: none" frameborder="0" height="300" width="240" name="frame2" src="http://thedragonring.me"></iframe>
</div>
```

Then, add some `<button>`s with a little script in their `onclick` attributes that will toggle whether the `display` attribute of the corresponding `<iframe>` is set to `none` or `block`, like so:

```
<div class="buttons">
  <button onclick="
    const el = document.querySelector('.iframes [name=frame1]');
    el.style.display = el.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
  ">
    Frame 1 (example.com)
  </button>
  <button onclick="
    const el = document.querySelector('.iframes [name=frame2]');
    el.style.display = el.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
  ">
    Frame 2 (thedragonring.me)
  </button>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could add a single button that will toggle between the 2 iframes:

```
<button onclick="
  const frame1 = document.querySelector('.iframes [name=frame1]'),
    frame2 = document.querySelector('.iframes [name=frame2]'),
    prev = frame1.style.display;
  frame1.style.display = prev === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
  frame2.style.display = prev === 'none' ? 'none' : '';
">
  Toggle
</button>
```

Basically, all these snippets of JS do is inverse the `display` attribute of the target `<iframe>`. You can see a demo @ http://jsfiddle.net/TheDragonRing/4bzrvnyh/

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with some methods below

```css
#if1, #if2{
  display:none;
}

#btn1:active ~ div #if1, #btn2:active ~ div #if2{
  display:block;
}

#rd1:checked ~ div #if1, #rd2:checked ~ div #if2{
  display:block;
}

#cb1:checked ~ div #if1, #cb2:checked ~ div #if2{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Reveal with active button -->
<button id="btn1">Reveal Frame 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Reveal Frame 2</button>
<br>
<!-- Reveal with checked radio -->
<input type="radio" id="rd1" name="reveal">
<label for="rd1">Reveal Frame 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="rd2" name="reveal">
<label for="rd2">Reveal Frame 2</label>
<br>
<!-- Reveal with checked checkbox -->
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1">
<label for="cb1">Reveal Frame 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2">
<label for="cb2">Reveal Frame 2</label>

<div>
<iframe width="100px" id="if1" src="http://google.com">Test</iframe>
<iframe width="200px" id="if2" src="http://amazon.com">Test</iframe>
</div>
```

The easiest way is use javascript than just html and css

Hope it helps